# How to let Xcode build apps and use playgrounds when parental control is enabled

Tags: macos, xcode, parental-controls

I would like to know how to let Xcode build apps and use playgrounds when parental control is enabled.
In fact app restriction is enabled, but even if Xcode is authorised it asks for authorisation every time when trying to build an app, and using playgrounds is simply impossible because it won't stop prompting for the authorisation even if it has been given.

Any ideas ?

EDIT : Now starting a bounty, don't hesitate to ask for details in the comments if you need them :)

Comment: To run a new app that app is going to have to be authorised. If that was not needed you could then build any app e.g firefox and get round the Parental control so I hope there is no way otherwise you have a security hole

Answer (score 1):

From my testing, I have found that if the **"Limit Applications" check box in Parental Controls is turned off**, but Xcode and the other applications that you want enabled are turned on in the "Allowed Apps" list, Xcode will only ask for authentication a few times:

1. On the first run of Xcode
2. On the first attempt at running an app created with Xcode
3. On the first attempt at running a playground

Even though it sounds weird to turn off Limit Applications, it seems like if the parental controls are set this way, Xcode will not repeatedly ask for authentication.